# Indian bank not refunding GST charges even after late payment penalties are refunded, Need interpretation help

Tags: india, tax-law

One bank sent a credit statement late, and later penalized my account with late payments and other financial charges. When I approached the bank citing their mistake they reversed such penzalization, but they are refusing to refund GST charges.

This is what bank is saying:

Please note as per the recent amendments, the Finance Bill has widened the scope of banking and financial services which are eligible for the levy of Good and Services Tax (GST ). As per the current Finance Bill, all fees and transaction charges, levied in your card account, will attract a rate of GST @ 18%. In terms of these guidelines provided by the Finance Bill, the Bank will be levying the GST accordingly and thereby wish to reiterate that the GST component once charged will not be reversed.

This is my argument:

This is the rule book of GST → https://www.cbic.gov.in/resources/htdocs-cbec/gst/30.07.2020_CGST%20Rules,%202017_(Part-A_Rules).pdf

Where is it written that GST when charged can't be reversed?
GST is an indirect tax, which is billed on top of actual goods or services. Penalizations are also a kind of service. Since all the late payment penalties are revered in lieu of HDFC bank being unable to send statements in time, how can you keep GST charges intact when their principal sources have been refunded.

Additionally,

You have to reverse the GST as original penalization has been reversed. Direct and Indirect taxes are levied on some principal components, not on components that have been reversed.

You are not an exemption from the revised [consumer protection act, 2019](https://egazette.nic.in/WriteReadData/2019/210422.pdf) clearly defines unfair trade contracts on page no. 8, and on point no. 46(vi), which clearly states that "(vi) imposing on the consumer any unreasonable charge, obligation or condition which puts such consumer to disadvantage;"

If you further deny the reversal. I know which body to approach and how to approach them.

VCan some one help me interpreting further so that I ca get back the GST charges?

Comment: When the bank reversed the original charges - did they indicate that they were admitting that they had wrongly charged you, or did they reverse them as a kind of "goodwill gesture"? The reason being that (depending on the circumstances) "statement credits" are not always accepted as payments towards a balance owing. That being the case, their position might be that you should have paid whatever was due and not relied on a partial statement credit, but although they're refunding the additional fee, that just them being nice to you and the original fee and its associated GST are still "valid".

Comment: They have refunded admitting that they were at fault, and they accepted overf email, by not delivering the statement in time. Also there are not Indian GST lawas that says GST's cant be refunded.

Comment: Did you sort out this matter? Recently something similar has happened with me. I received my credit card statement with a payment due of Rs 700 on 12th December 2022. The payment due date was 30th December 2023. On 12th December due to a refund I received from an online purchase, and amount of Rs 832 was credited to my balance. Therefore, it seemed to me that I have to pay nothing. However, in my next bill, I was charged a late fee for the Rs 700. The reason they gave is that refunds are not accepted as payments and I have to pay the minimum amount due. continued ....

Comment: However, this seems to be in violation of RBI guidelines available here: https://www.rbi.org.in/scripts/FS_Notification.aspx?Id=12300&fn=2&Mode=0, point 10(e). When I confronted the bank, they tell me that they can reverse the late fee fine, but not the GST levied on the late fee.

Comment: Yes, I told them about GST laws, and they have to refund me. If they do not refund, you can file a GST complaint with the GST tax commissioner of your state. GST has to be refunded if the principle amount is refunded. If you are registered under GST then this comes under input tax credit. Open to further question, and will answer what I know.